# Two identical object names; how to make VS ignore one of them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, encapsulation

I have basic `User` model class that I am using but the problem is that in ASP.NET MVC there is already some property named `User` that is getting HTTP authentication information.

Can I somehow make Visual Studio 2012 ignore the other one and use mine? It would be pretty unpractical to write `Website.Models.Users.User` every time I want to access it.

Here is a picture for you to understand my problem better.
[image]

Comment: I have very similar problem.

Comment: Near impossible to read that screen shot. Why not post the _text_ of the error and the class definition instead?

Comment: @Oded Just open the screenshot in new window, then you will be able to see it in its actual size.

Comment: So, making it easy for those who would answer is not something you are willing to do?

Comment: @Oded Screenshot is just some additional information, there is no error. Question should be perfectly clear even without image. I just added it as additional information.

Comment: Why not just refactor your User class to have a more personal name? MyAppUser or similar

Comment: @Xander Yea probably this is the best choice, I just wondered if I can somehow disable it inside VS. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Are you trying to access a static member on your class? Because then I can see your problem. But you can still use your class in non-static ways, like `User u = new User();`, because "your" `User` is a type (class) while "their" `User` is not (it is an instance property that you inherit).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have static methods in it so this is not the issue. Issue is in naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alias your `Namespace` or `Class`, or Microsoft's `Namespace` or `Class`:

Replace:

`using Website.Models.Users;`

With:

`using myUsers = Website.Models.Users;`

or

`using myUser = Website.Models.Users.User;`

Then use it as: `if(myUser.` or `if(myUsers.User.` in your code

Alternatively, you could just rename your classes so there are no collisions.

Comment: @Steve You don't need to. Look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

While Tom Studee had a good idea, there's an even better one.

Not only can you alias namespaces, you can alias classes!

Use this;

```
using HTTPUser = Website.Models.Users.User;
```

and then when you want to access that use use `HTTPUser` for that type of user and just `User` for the normal one.

Comment: +1, I could've been more clear this was possible in my answer.